# Understanding Pointer Behavior and Copy Elision in Object Returns Pre- and Post-C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

I'm trying to understand how pointers within objects behave when these objects are returned from functions, particularly in relation to copy elision and temporary object creation in C++ standards before and after `C++17`. Below is my code example:

```
struct A {
    void* p;
    A() : p(this) {}
    A(const A&); // Disable trivial copyability
};

A f() {
    A x;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    A a;  // OK: a.p points to a
    A b = f(); // Concern: b.p could be dangling and point to the x inside f
    A c = A(); // (until C++17) Concern: c.p could be dangling and point to a temporary
               // (since C++17) OK: c.p points to c; no temporary is involved
}
```

**Specifically, my concerns are:**

In `A b = f();`, is it correct that b.p could be a dangling pointer pointing to x inside `f()`, depending on whether the compiler applies RVO before C++17?

For `A c = A();`, I understand that in C++17, `c.p` points directly to c with no temporary involved. But prior to C++17, could `c.p` be a dangling pointer if a temporary object is created and then destroyed?

I would appreciate any clarification or insights into how these scenarios are handled in different C++ standards.

P.S. I specifically meant `C++11` and `C++14` as this code won't compile in `C++03`

Comment: I'd say as a rule of thumb: if it works with copy constructor and move constructor deleted for a class, it's safe. So `f` isn't safe, because it's NRVO. `A g() { return {}; }` on the other hand would be safe.

Comment: What you are describing in the code (the `f()` function) is NRVO, which is allowed but not required.  URVO is required as of C++17.

Comment: NRVO requires availability of move&|copy constructor as fallback strategy. URVO doesn't require that. So if it compiles with deleted copy+move constructor, it's not NRVO. The official term for copy elision is direct initialization, which informally means `this` equals the `addressof` final resultant object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a copy is elided, it means that the the source and destination objects are the same object.  There is no copy; that's the whole point.

> In `A b = f();`, is it correct that b.p could be a dangling pointer pointing to x inside `f()`, depending on whether the compiler applies RVO before C++17?

No.  Because `A`'s copy constructor isn't implemented, the only way for it to possibly be returned from `f` is via NRVO, in which case `b` and `x` *are the same object*.  Behind the scenes `main` passes a pointer to `f` into which `f` initializes its return object.  When (N)RVO is applied, `main` and `f` simply both use that storage directly as `b` and `x`, respectively, instead of `f` copying `x` into the return value and then `main` copying from the return value to `b`.

> For `A c = A();`, I understand that in C++17, `c.p` points directly to `c` with no temporary involved. But prior to C++17, could `c.p` be a dangling pointer if a temporary object is created and then destroyed?

No.  Because `A`'s copy constructor isn't implemented there's no way for a temporary to be copied to `c`.  That means that the only way the program could possibly compile is if the copy is elided and `c` is directly initialized.

---

Note that I don't think it's a good idea to rely on this behavior.  It would be very easy for someone to get a random link error (because NRVO didn't get applied in some situation) and change the copy constructor to `A(const A&) {}` to "fix" the problem, which *could* easily lead to dangling pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great explanations! The part you said behind the scenes main passes a pointer to f ... do you mean this ?"the compiler "passes a pointer" to the space allocated for b in the main function into the f function. When f constructs the object x, it actually constructs it directly in the space pointed to by this pointer — that is, where b will be in main. This way, x and b are essentially the same object, and no copy or move operation is needed to return x from f." and does the compiler always passes a pointer only if there is RVO or NRVO?

Comment: @Sami Yes, that's correct.  See my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955310/how-does-c-abi-deal-with-rvo-and-nrvo/48955636#48955636) for a bit more context.  The caller is always responsible for allocating space for the return object (in all calling convention's I'm familiar with, at least).

Answer (score 2):

> is it correct that `b.p` could be a dangling pointer pointing to `x` inside
> `f()`, depending on whether the compiler applies RVO before C++17?

There is no RVO (which is mandatory) here, but possibly NRVO (*named* return value optimization), which is *not* mandatory, so yes, it could very well be dangling if you enabled the copy constructor. Without it, it'll fail to link in case NRVO isn't selected.

Note: This is true in C++17 too! NRVO does not mandate that there will be copy/move elision of `x` -> `b` and if you `= delete;` the copy constructor, it will not compile even in C++17.

> For `A c = A();`, I understand that in C++17, `c.p` points directly to `c` with no temporary involved. But prior to C++17, could `c.p` be a dangling pointer if a temporary object is created and then destroyed?

For C++17, that's correct. For C++14, the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided, so in your case, it would fail to link if elision isn't selected by the compiler. If you `= delete;` the copy constructor, it'll fail to compile, even if it could elide the copy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! very helpful! i have a question: 

if we have a copy and move constructor deleted and in the 'main' function we have 
' A b = f(); ' and even if we defined f as inline 'inline A f(){}' , would we still get error in c++11 and c++14 because copy and move are not callable or because on inline it wouldn't cause any issue?! like instead of 'A b= f();' compiler turned it to 'A b;'? is it possible?

Comment: I think the inline keyword is considered a suggestion to the compiler, not an obligation, and it can choose to inline f() or not. If inlined, in C++17, it doesn't affect the outcome because of guaranteed copy elision, which allows the prvalue N() to be constructed directly in place as auto n in main. However, in C++11 and C++14, even with inlining and copy elision, a copy or move constructor must still be callable. if A's copy and move constructors are deleted, this results in a compile-time error in these earlier versions of the standard regardless of being inlined or not. am i right?

Comment: @Sami The `inline` keyword does not change the semantics of a function call at all.  It's not even really a suggestion to the compiler to inline calls to a function.  All the `inline` keyword does these days is allow you to define a function in multiple translation units without violating the ODR (as long as they're all identical).  Even if a function call _is_ inlined, it doesn't change the semantics of the call at all.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, you're really awesome! every time I ask questions here, you explain a concept really well and talk about nuances I have never heard of ! I've learned something new about 'inline'. thank you!