# Will this do default move operation

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have a function foo:

```
std::vector<T> foo() {
  std::vector<T> result;
  // populate result
  {
    /*
       for loop with result.push_back().
       ignore real code.
    */
  }
  //
  return result;    <-- note there without std::move
}
```

Will it do extra copy if I assign like the following?

```
const auto v = foo();   <-- will it move the vector by default?
const auto &v = foo();  <-- same question as above, assuming T is movable
```

I am in particular interested in the second case as for the first case it's
very likely the compiler knows to *move* the result from foo() to v.

```
const auto &v = foo();
```

For this case, the foo() function creates a temp *result*. Now as v is a reference, it can't move *result* to v. Thus it needs to create a new copy. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Are you asking if [NRVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233879/move-or-named-return-value-optimization-nrvo) would work here? You can try printing the address of `result` and `v` to check if they point to the same location. As far as I can [see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/008e806a76afed61), they are printing the same address. So a good guess would be, there is no copy being made.

Comment: For both cases? for the second case, *v* is defined as *const auto &v*?

Comment: @badola it seems for both cases we don't do extra copy. I am curious how does the compiler knows for the second case?

Comment: `const &` is allowed to bind to a temporary.

Answer (score 3):

The compilers are permitted to *any and all code transformations that do not change the observable behavior of the program*, by applying the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

However, [copy_elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is an exception from the **as-if rule**: the compiler may remove calls to move- and copy-constructors and the matching calls to the destructors of temporary objects *even if those calls have observable side effects*. To witness these side effects, you have to use `-fno-elide-constructors` option while compiling.

From the [copy_elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) page, we should look at the clause:

> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile
>   object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function
>   parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class
>   type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This
>   variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value
>   optimization".

When the compiler sees the below structure, it knows it is a candidate for NRVO.

```
T FunctionName ( ... )
{
    T a;
    ...
    return a;
}
```

Which matches the code structure of your problem.

```
std::vector<T> foo() {
  std::vector<T> result;
  // populate result
  {
    /*
       for loop with result.push_back().
       ignore real code.
    */
  }
  return result;
}
```

Case 1 -

```
const auto v = foo();   <-- will it move the vector by default?
```

What you are witnessing is not move-semantics, it is just NRVO.
So the question doesn't have any relevance here.

Case 2 -

```
const auto &v = foo();  <-- same question as above, assuming T is movable
```

It doesn't matter if `T` is movable. There is no `move` happening here.
The concept that is taking place is `const &` can bind to a temporary.

We would achieve the same result in pre-C++11 compiler as well, which didn't have move-semantics support.

Comment: NRVO is optional.

Answer (score 0):

For both cases, it seems there's no extra copy, seen from this [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/008e806a76afed61)