# Can you use make_unique directly in a function call?

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

I am attempting to update some code that hands off a new object. The goal is to manage it with a smart pointer. Boiled down, it looks much like this:

```
class X
{
    shared_ptr<Y> yptr;

    X() : yptr(Y::create(new Z())){}
};

class Y
{
    Z* zptr;
    static shared_ptr<Y> create(Z* zp)
    {
        if(!zp) return nullptr;
        else return shared_ptr<Y>(new Y(zp));
    }

    Y(Z* zp) : zptr(zp){}
}
```

So far this seems to work:

```
class X
{
    shared_ptr<Y> yptr;

    X() : yptr(Y::create(  std::move(  std::make_unique<Z>(Z())  )  )){}
};

class Y
{
    unique_ptr<Z> zptr;
    static shared_ptr<Y> create(unique_ptr<Z> zp)
    {
        if(!zp) return nullptr;
        else return shared_ptr<Y>(new Y(std::move(zp)));
    }

    Y(unique_ptr<Z> zp) : zptr(std::move(zp)){}
}
```

My question is, is the first std::move() (around make_unique) necessary? Visual Studio doesn't seem to mind either way. I'd rather have an accurate understanding before I start making similar changes elsewhere where performance is more critical.

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::make_shared()` if you actually want a `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: All that `std::move` does is cast the object to a prvalue.  If the object already is a prvalue (for example, it doesn't have a name... it's a temporary), then `std::move` is superfluous.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ The code involved is a factory method that assigns its members on creation. The object returned by it is intended to be the sole owner of the item managed by the unique_ptr. A shared_ptr would work in this case but it betrays the intent.

Comment: @françois-andrieux And it is, I'll adjust the above. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! The move around `make_unique` is unnecessary.

`std::move` exists to convert an l-value reference `&` (which refers to an existing object) into an r-value reference `&&` (which represents a temporary value, or something that can be moved from).

If you assign a `unique_ptr` to a named variable, then you indeed need to `std::move` from it if you want to transfer its ownership (usually; see below). You cannot directly bind an r-value reference to a variable.

The value returned by an expression or function call, such as the `unique_ptr` returned by `make_shared`, is a temporary, and so it naturally can bind to an r-value expression and be moved-from implicitly.

Note that there are some special cases where you do and don't need to use `std::move`:

- If you have a named variable whose type is an r-value reference, you *do* need to `std::move` it to avoid passing it by copy:

  `MyClass(std::string&& s) : m_mystring(s) {}` **copy**-constructs `m_mystring`

  `MyClass(std::string&& s) : m_mystring(std::move(s)) {}` move-constructs `m_mystring`

  In general, variables with names do no implicitly get moved from.
- If you are returning an local variable by value from a function, that object may get moved from automatically, in the so-called [Named Return Value Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233879/move-or-named-return-value-optimization-nrvo). This gives a nice speed boost to returning by value. You don't need to think much about this point in practice, just be aware that `return std::move(whatever);` is almost always wrong.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I have a followup, since you brought up a similar situation. If the function that the make_unique is being passed into has to pass it on to a constructor before it is actually used, is the std::move() now necessary, or is it only needed inside the constructor itself (the final destination)?

Comment: @M.Parker From Scott Meyers' _Essential Modern C++_, "a parameter
is always an lvalue, even if its type is an rvalue reference. That is, given `void f(Widget&& w);`, the parameter `w` is an lvalue, even though its type is rvalue-reference-to-`Widget`."

Comment: This might seem like a minor point, but the question was "is the first std::move() *necessary*", (not "is the first std::move() *un*necessary).  So your answer is in fact "No!", not "Yes!".    I got derailed for several minutes trying to make sense of your answer, because I saw your "Yes!" but missed your "un", and thought you were saying the opposite of what you are actually saying.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes**

The function call `std::make_unique<Z>()` returns an rvalue, so there is no need to wrap it in `std::move()` if you are passing it directly into another function.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is the first std::move() (around make_unique) necessary?

if you mean this line:

```
X() : yptr(Y::create(  std::move(  std::make_unique<Z>(Z())  )  )){}
```

then no, it is completely unnecessary as `std::make_unique<Z>` returns temporary which is already `prvalue`. You can do something like this:

```
auto ptr = std::move( std::move( std::move( std::make_unique<Z>() ) ) );
```

instead of

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<Z>();
```

but all of that `moves` are unnecessary and the fact it is compiled clearly shows that.