# Passing cv::Mat by reference

Tags: c++, opencv, c++17, opencv-mat

I have a function where instead of returning a `cv::Mat` I want to pass in a reference to an existing data structure. I am trying to reduce unnecessary copying of `cv::Mat` Function currently looks like:

```
cv::Mat HSV::apply(const cv::Mat& input) {
  cv::Mat image, output;

  cv::cvtColor(input, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
  cv::inRange(image, m_Low, m_High, output);
  return output;
}
```

I am trying to convert it to -

```
void HSV::apply(const cv::Mat& input) {
  cv::Mat image, output;

  cv::cvtColor(input, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
  cv::inRange(image, m_Low, m_High, output);
}
```

Now in another node, I used to call this function as follows:

```
Detection::Detection(ros::NodeHandle& nh)
    : m_Filter_(std::make_unique<HSV>()), { 
  m_ImageSub = nh.subscribe("/image_raw", 10, &Detector::inputCb, this);
}

void Detector::inputCb(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg) {
  cv::Mat image = ImageConverter::convertToCvMat(msg);
  cv::Mat finalImage = m_Filter_->apply(image);
}
```

How can I call the function now if I am passing it by reference?

Comment: cv::Mat already contain refcounting. the only thing you're affecting with an explicit reference is that *the object itself* can be affected by you, in terms of shape/size, element type, etc.

Comment: Other than the premature (and unnecessary) optimization, why are you calling `inRange` on an empty `Mat`? Other than having a side effect of changing `hsvImage` (whatever that is, some global?) both of those variations of `HSV::apply` seem rather useless.

Comment: that part I just autocorrected with `s/hsvImage/image/` assuming there isn't an unseen member variable and OP meant the local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your converted function is correct. It should be

```
void HSV::apply(const cv::Mat& input, cv::Mat& output) {
  cv::Mat image;

  cv::cvtColor(input, hsvImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
  cv::inRange(image, m_Low, m_High, output);
}
```

That function would be called like this

```
void Detector::inputCb(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg) {
  cv::Mat image = ImageConverter::convertToCvMat(msg);
  cv::Mat finalImage;
  m_Filter_->apply(image, finalImage);
}
```

However please note that [named return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233879/move-or-named-return-value-optimization-nrvo) (NRVO) means that no copying occurs when you `return output;` so this might be an unnecessary change.

Answer (score 3):

`cv::Mat` already contain ref-counting. The instance contains some metadata and a reference to backing memory. Multiple instances can use the same backing memory.

Passing one "by value" merely creates a new Mat that uses the same memory as the Mat you passed in.

Same goes for returning a `cv::Mat`, independently of all the language-level shenanigans and optimizations that C++ offers.

Passing by (C++) reference is fine though. The only thing you're affecting (or could, if it weren't `const`) with an explicit reference is that *the instance itself* can be affected by you, in terms of shape/size, element type, etc.

Don't overcomplicate it. **Measure** first.